# Video.js on IE9 gives errors on preload=auto - and IE poster not showing issues

Tags: internet-explorer-9, preload, video.js

I'm showing some videos on a page using video.js.   The videos have a poster image defined, and had preload=auto set up, with no controls.   (All of the playback is done through the API).

Everything seems to work in just about any browser EXCEPT for IE9.   There, sometimes (not always), you get a Video Error on one or more of the videos, and if you try to play the video it gives you an error that the video is not ready.

The ONLY fix I've been able to find is to set preload=none, but that's unacceptable, because with preload=none, the video starts up with a black rectangle for a couple seconds while it loads when you start to play it.   We also get that black rectangle on all IE browsers and I've not been able to figure out a fix for it - it's supposed to be showing the poster.   But that seemed to happen when we got rid of the controls.

I'd be okay with preload=none, even with the black rectangle, if there was some interface I could use to begin loading the video from the API, but I can't find one.  So I need one of three possible solutions - in order of preference:

- something which fixes the IE9 specific problem with preload=auto
- something which lets us use the API after Domready to explicitly preload the videos when  the tag is set to preload=none
- something which can get the poster to show instead of the black rectangle until the video is ready to play on ALL browsers.

Any ideas?